# Continuous Deployment using WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, winrm

[image]In WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment, I am trying to make some changes in Web Deploy Parameter File. The Task is completed but the values in parameter file is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Deploy Parameter file is xml file (e.g. SetParameters.xml)  with setparameter section and Web Deploy Package is the zip file that is generated by publishing web project through Web Deployment Package method. (Check your task)

For example:

SetParameters.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/WebGeneralDemo_deploy" />
  <setParameter name="DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" value="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebGeneralDemo-20161031015123.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebGeneralDemo-20161031015123;Integrated Security=True" />
</parameters>
```

WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task:

Web Deploy package: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\web.zip`

Override Parameters: `name="DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String",value="test"`

The Web Deployment Parameter file input box can be empty, which uses default SetParameters.xml file in the same folder.

On the other hand, the related parameters in parameters.xml file will be added to the SetParameters.xml file when builds the package.

More information: How to: [Use Web Deploy Parameters in a Web Deployment Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110).aspx).